# How to access KnowledgeArticle content via REST API

Tags: rest-api, knowledge, articles

Does anyone know if it's possible to access KnowledgeArticle content over the Salesforce REST API? All I can find are the [KnowledgeArticle](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticle.htm) and [KnowledgeArticleVersion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm) objects which seem to have only the Title and Summary of the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully up to date with Salesforce Knowledge articles, but I did find [Retrieve a Version of an Article](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/knowledge_devpre/index_CSH.htm#knowledge_REST_retrieve_article_version.htm) in the Salesforce Knowledge Developer's Guide.

It's a bit short on details, which I suspect is related to the API being in pre-release.

There is also the [Salesforce Knowledge Objects Data Model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm). It has plenty of polymorphic references to other sObjects, but nothing that stands out as "content" to me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some more information to expand upon [Daniel's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger) findings:

Yes, you can retrieve article content from salesforce via the REST API but the method is not very straightforward. This is related to the fact that all articles are versioned. This means that the article ID is separate from the ID of the currently published version of that article (master ID). This master ID is what you need to query for if you want the article content.

Below is an example of fetching article content:

**First, you have to fetch the master ID for the article:**

```
// Request  
services/data/v29.0/knowledgeManagement/articles/{article-id}

// Result (truncated to for simplicity)
{
  …
  "draftArticleMasterVersionId": "am0k000000000HmAAB",
  "onlineArticleMasterVersionId": "am0k000000000HmAAA"   // <-- Master ID
  ...
}
```

**Then use the master ID to obtain the article content via your article sobject:**

> **Note**: This will be API name of whatever you chose to name your Article Type in salesforce (Setup > Customize > Knowledge > Article
>   Types). In my case my article type label is Knowledge Base so the
>   sobject is "Knowledge_Base__kav"

```
// Request
services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Knowledge_Base__kav/am0k000000000HmAAA

// Result (truncated to for simplicity)
{
  "Title": "How to do some action",
  "Summary": "This article show you how to do some action",
  "ArticleNumber": "000001260",
  "Description__c": "Example article description on how to do some action"
}
```

Comment: So this only seems to cover getting a title and summary, it seems like the actual content is not available. Is that correct?